# Local variable becoming NoneType and I'm not sure why

Tags: python

I'm writing the following function to format some text from a file object 'item':

```python
def clean(item):
    lines = open(str(item)).readlines()
    outp = []
    switch = 1

    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            line = re.sub(' +', ' ', line)
            if '%' in line:
                line = line.replace('%', ' per cent')
            if line.startswith('Note'):
                switch = 2

            if line.startswith('l\t'):
                line = line.split('\t')
                line[0] = '<@01_bullet_point>l<@$p>'
                line = '\t'.join(line)
                outp.append(get_prefix(switch,1) + line)
            else:
                outp.append(get_prefix(switch,2) + line)
            outp.append('\n')
    return ''.join(outp)
```

I'm getting a TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

I googled around for solutions but found http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/, whose solution 4 seemed to confirm that I was on the right track.

The other function(s) this is referencing are confirmed working so I know the problem must be in here but, having tried to find related SO questions and checked my copy of Python in a Nutshell, I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. My best guess was something to do with variable scope but I can't see it and, again, searching turned up nothing I could understand as the same problem. I expect I'm missing something obvious but any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT
get_prefix is:

```python
def get_prefix(section, type):
    if section == 1:
        if type == 1:
            prefix = '@01_bullets:'
        elif type == 2:
            prefix = '@04_section_sub_subhead:'
        else:
            prefix = '@06_body_text:'

    else:
        if type == 2:
            prefix = '@14_notes_sub_sub_heading:'
        else:
            prefix = '@16_notes_text:'

    return prefix
```

I can't see how it might return None.

The full traceback is:

```
File "rep_builder.py", line 65, in <module>
`rep.write(clean(item))`
File "rep_builder.py", line 36, in clean
`outp.append(get_prefix(switch,2) + line)`
TypeError: unsupported operand types for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Sorry for slow updates I'm working across two unconnectable machines (long story).

Comment: is it possible that your call to `get_prefix` is returning `None`?

Comment: In these situations, it's nice if you post the full traceback as that usually pinpoints which line is causing problems and it makes it much easier to figure out why.

Comment: Tip: Start up an `ipython` session (install it if you don't have it) and try out your code that way. In the event of an exception, you can enter "debug" as the very next command and it will put you into the debugger in the appropriate place.

Comment: @kwatford thanks for the tip. I'll need to try it when I get home as I can't install anything on the machines I'm using since they're locked down.

Comment: First off sorry for the formatting error on the original question (fixed), which happened when I was adding spaces for SO code block rather than being an error in the original code. This is turning out to be really odd. I've checked this code at home now and it works perfectly first time. I'll rerun on my work machine when I go in tomorrow to try and chase down what on earth is going on. Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Comment: See accepted answer for why I'm a fool and an apology for wasting people's time. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your indentation. Are you sure `get_prefix` doesn't look something like this? (I ask because the indentation in `clean` is wrong):

```
def get_prefix(section, type):
    if section == 1:
        if type == 1:
            prefix = '@01_bullets:'
        elif type == 2:
            prefix = '@04_section_sub_subhead:'
        else:
            prefix = '@06_body_text:'

    else:
        if type == 2:
            prefix = '@14_notes_sub_sub_heading:'
        else:
            prefix = '@16_notes_text:'

        return prefix
```

Indented as above, `get_prefix` will return `None` if `section` equals `1`.

Comment: get_prefix is as it appears in the question. Please also see my latest comment on the question for a somewhat odd update. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: Actually I'm an idiot and you're right. I've somehow diddled the indentation when I yanked this function in from the previous, working version of this script and then fixed it myself when I was re-indenting for SO's four spaces rule. Sorry everyone for wasting your time and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

The only `+` operation is `outp.append(get_prefix(switch,1) + line)` and similar `outp.append(get_prefix(switch,2) + line)` - that means that `get_prefix()` is the culprit, returning `None` here.

Comment: I would suggest that get_prefix is returning None because there is no return statement in it

Comment: @XavierCombelle - either that or just a `return`

Comment: Thanks. get_prefix is now included in the question. I don't think it's capable of returning None, but I'd be happy to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your call to `get_prefix` is resulting in `None` being returned.

Given the error message and the available source code, this would be the most likely cause as it's the only place you are trying to concatenate something unknown and a string using the `+` operator. I.e.,

```
outp.append(get_prefix(switch,1) + line)
```

or

```
outp.append(get_prefix(switch,2) + line)
```

EDIT: one approach to check your `get_prefix` function is to give your `prefix` variable a default string value at the start of the function, and see if that eliminates the problem. That would point to that function, though I have to agree, I don't see how that code could return `None` as shown now.